# Input field increase value form method

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have problem, I have one input field type number, when I click to increase value, my value in `priceForAllProducts` property is increase. But I want to lower the value also on click. This is my code:

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <input type="number" id="numberOfProduct" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of product" min="1" 
    [(ngModel)]="products.numberOfProduct" (click)="setPrice( products.price)">

</div>
```

My `TypeScript`:

```
  setPrice( price: number) {
    this.priceForAllProducts += price;
  }
```

Comment: Lower the number on what condition? When to increase and when to decrease?

Comment: You should have defined logic to identify when to increase and when to decrease the price. May be you should have a '+' and '-' icon and on click of it you can update the price as needed.

Comment: Can you pleas set any example of how set icon  '+' and '-' , and on this icon I will be set methods and this is be done.

Comment: a native input type as number did implement a increase and decrease button (I think almost in all modern browser), so there is not necessary to implement by you self.